# How to create a system restore point?

Tags: windows, winapi, snapshot, volume-shadow-service

[image]

Installing paint.net, I found a string *Creating system restore point...*
I guess it is creating a restore point for Volume Shadow Service. -Isn't it? I'm not sure.

If I'm right, how do I do this in my app?
Let me know please if there are proper Apis.

Comment: I think paint.net is open source. Download source and have a look. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the System Restore API.

See the documentation for the [`SRSetRestorePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378941.aspx) function, along with [adetailed example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315530).